# How can I concatenate strings

Tags: r

I did a bit of research on this and tried to get it working on my own, but to no avail.  I'm trying to concatenate a couple strings together so I can download CSV files from the web.

This tiny script works fine for one stock.

```
read.csv("http://financials.morningstar.com/ajax/exportKR2CSV.html?&t=AAPL",header=T,stringsAsFactors = F,skip = 2)[,-c(12)]->spreadsheet
```

I am trying to concatenate these strings, but things are just not working out for me.

```
stocks <- c("AXP","BA","CAT","CSCO")

for (s in stocks) 
{
paste("read.csv("http://financials.morningstar.com/ajax/exportKR2CSV.html?&t=",s,header=T,stringsAsFactors = F,skip = 2)[,-c(12)]->spreadsheet)
paste("write.table(stockdata, "C:/Users/rshuell001/Desktop/files/",s,".csv", sep=",", row.names=FALSE, col.names=FALSE))
}


Or.....


stocks <- c("AXP","BA","CAT","CSCO")

for (s in stocks) 
{
cat("read.csv("http://financials.morningstar.com/ajax/exportKR2CSV.html?&t=",s,header=T,stringsAsFactors = F,skip = 2)[,-c(12)]->spreadsheet)
cat("write.table(stockdata, "C:/Users/rshuell001/Desktop/files/",s,".csv", sep=",", row.names=FALSE, col.names=FALSE))
}
```

Comment: You also either need to alternate single and double quotes, or escape them, e.g. `paste("\"Hello", "world\"")`.

Answer (score 2):

We can use `sprintf` to create a `vector` of urls.

```
urls <- sprintf("http://financials.morningstar.com/ajax/exportKR2CSV.html?&t=%s", stocks)
```

Then, loop through the links and read it

```
lst <- lapply(urls, read.csv, header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE, skip=2)
lst1 <- lapply(lst, `[`, -12)
```

and then we can write the files by looping over the `list`

Or as @Richard Scriven mentioned, `fread` from `data.table` would be an option as it have `drop` argument to drop the columns

```
library(data.table)
lst <- lapply(urls, fread, skip= 2, drop=12)
```

Comment: Wow!  Very cool.  Only one problem remains.  The stock tickers are gone, so I can't really tell what is what.  How can I get the tickers in the data set to identify what I'm looking at?  Or, how can I simply save each file separately, with the ticker being the name of the file?

Comment: @ryguy7272  You can name the `lst` with the `stocks` i.e `names(lst) <- stocks` and if you need to write it to a file `lapply(names(lst1), function(nm) write.csv(lst1[[nm]], paste0("file", nm,, ".csv"), row.names=FALSE, quote=FALSE))`

Comment: Trying to make this work now, but my VS keeps crashing.